# when we move from one page to other how to make changes to that respective nav link in css

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, bootstrap-4

One way is to add an active attribute to the nav-link on which page we are:

```
 <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link navLink active" href="userhome.php">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link navLink" href="pool.php">Pool</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link navLink" href="tickets.php">Tickets</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link navLink" href="#">Winners</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
```

```
 <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link navLink " href="userhome.php">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link navLink active" href="pool.php">Pool</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link navLink" href="tickets.php">Tickets</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link navLink" href="#">Winners</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
```

... and so on

is there any other alternatives in javascript or CSS?

Comment: I'm assuming you are trying to highlight the current page link. Is that correct? How are you rendering your HTML for your navigation? Is it manual, e.g. building out each page by hand?

Comment: yes, I want to highlight the current page link. for example, if I am on the home page the nav-link stating home must be highlighted until I switch to another page. Then to whichever page I go, that must be highlighted and home nav-link must become normal.   I am using bootstrap and PHP code. where I am not writing the nav again and again for a different page instead I wrote it once and including that part through PHP.

Comment: HTML  `<ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link navLink" href="userhome.php">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link navLink " href="pool.php">Pool</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link navLink" href="tickets.php">Tickets</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link navLink" href="#">Winners</a>
          </li>
        </ul>`

Comment: i m calling the code through php :    ```<?php include 'inc/nav.php'; ?>```

Comment: so i need method where i can make nav-links highlighted through css or javascript.

Comment: CSS alone cannot do this. CSS would only be used to style the active link. Since you're using PHP to call an include, let's use PHP to do this - no JS necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using PHP to check to see what page you're on by setting a variable on each page. Since it appears you have very few pages, this should work for you. We can also use the URL if necessary:

At the top of each of your pages, add a variable before anything else (line one of your php file), switching out the name of the page. I'll use the `pool` page as an example:

```
<?php $current_page = 'pool' ?>
```

Now in your `nav.php`:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link navLink <?php if ($current_page === 'home') echo 'active'; ?>" href="userhome.php">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link navLink <?php if ($current_page === 'pool') echo 'active'; ?>" href="pool.php">Pool</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link navLink <?php if ($current_page === 'tickets') echo 'active'; ?>" href="tickets.php">Tickets</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link navLink <?php if ($current_page === 'winners') echo 'active'; ?>" href="#">Winners</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

What this does is checks the `$current_page` variable and if it matches, it adds the active class to your `nav-link` element.

Here's a way you can do it without setting a variable on each page. This will compare the the page returned by the server with current file name.

```
<?php
    // Get the current page returned by the server.
    $current_page_uri = str_replace( '/', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
    // Get the current file name
    $current_file = basename( $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] );
    // Active class if current page uri and current file are the same
    $active = ( $current_page_uri === $current_file ) ? 'active' : '';
    ?>

<ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link navLink <?php echo $active ?>" href="userhome.php">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link navLink <?php echo $active ?>" href="pool.php">Pool</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link navLink <?php echo $active ?>" href="tickets.php">Tickets</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link navLink <?php echo $active ?>" href="#">Winners</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] returns the current file name

So we can use this to match the filenames of links with the current

You can also put extra class name and give your own style

```
<?php $curr = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>
 <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link navLink <?php if($curr=="username.php") echo " active"; ?>" href="userhome.php">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link navLink <?php if($curr=="pool.php") echo " active"; ?>" href="pool.php">Pool</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link navLink <?php if($curr=="tickets.php") echo " active"; ?>" href="tickets.php">Tickets</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link navLink <?php if($curr=="winners.php") echo " active"; ?>" href="winners.php">Winners</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Hope! you got your answer